# What is the integral of this function?

Tags: integration

What will be the answer of this integral? 
$$ \int_{-\pi} ^\pi e^{-jw(N-1)}. \frac {\sin^2(wN/2)}{\sin^2(w/2)}\,dw $$

Answer (score 1):

Is $N$ a positive integer?  And $j^2=-1$?  Answer: $2\pi$.

Comment: yes N is positve intergal and for every positive integer answer will be 2$\pi$ e.g for N=2 or N=3 answer will remain same or it is dependent on the value of N too? and please if you can show me a step of two on how to get to this answer. thanks